# using MPI_Op_create with external libraries functions such as boost or GSL

Tags: c++, c, boost, mpi, gsl

I'm just wondering if this is possible and if it is would any one have an example of using the MPI_Op_create to create a Op with a function that has many gsl and or boost functions inside of it to pass it on to an mpi_reduce command. In my situation order doesn't matter but serial and Openmp are too slow for what i want to do, so i want to try to convert it to mpi.

instead of a standard C example

```
void addem ( int *, int *, int *, MPI_Datatype * );

void addem(int *invec, int *inoutvec, int *len, MPI_Datatype *dtype)
{
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i<*len; i++ )
        inoutvec[i] += invec[i];
}
```

which is then passed on to

MPI_Op_create( (MPI_User_function *)addem, 1, &op );

i would  change that to something similar but much more complicated then this

```
void addgsl(gsl_vector* vec,gsl matrix* mat, int num,.....,MPI_Datatype *dtype)

 for (int i=0; i <num; i++) {
     //some complicated boost or gsl mathematical formula here
                             }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no limitations on what user-defined operations can do: they are simply given some elements from the input and are expected to compute a result.  The only requirement for user ops is that they are associative.  There is also no way to predict how many elements the function will get: this is up to the MPI implementation, and is specified by the `len` parameter.

Comment: it says I can specific associate + commutative or not(from the openMPI doc , might be different for different implementations) in my situation order doesn't matter so this is good news thanks